# Parametric Types: Accept subtypes of a given type, but not the type itself

Tags: struct, types, julia

consider the following code:

```jl
abstract type MyDimension end
abstract type My2D <: MyDimension end
abstract type My3D <: MyDimension end

mutable struct Shape{T<:MyDimension}

end
```

Currently you can declare variables of type `Shape{My2D}`, `Shape{My3D}` and `Shape{MyDimension}`.

Is there any way that allows the first two but not `Shape{MyDimension}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
mutable struct Shape{T<:Union{My2D, My3D}}
end
```

or create an intermediate type:

```
abstract type My2or3D <: MyDimension end
abstract type My2D <: My2or3D end
abstract type My3D <: My2or3D end
mutable struct Shape{T<:Union{My2or3D}}
end
```

The choice should be made considering if you want `Shape` to have a fixed types that it accepts or you want to potentially allow defining additional types that it accepts without having to redefine the `Shape` type.